# "If I had not rented a car" or "If I didn't rent a car"

Tags: grammar, verbs, conditional-constructions

Assume it is raining now. I want to tell my friend, fortunately I rented a car yesterday so we can go to the party today even though it is raining now.

Which statement is correct?

> If I hadn't rented a car, how we would go to the party in this rain?

or

> If I didn't rent a car, how we would go into the party in this rain?

Comment: Both are a bit awkward as they have double negatives going on.  I think i would phrase it as: Luckily, ( or Isn't it lucky that) I rented this car, otherwise the rain may have prevented us from attending the party.  To straighten it out a bit further: The rain might have prevented us from going to the party if I had not rented a car.

Comment: BTW, the second is not quite grammatical: If I didn't rent a car, how 'would' we (be able to) go to the party in this rain?  You need the 'would' or possibly 'could' here and one does not go into a party - we go to parties or arrive at them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Michael that there are better ways to phrase this statement, although I don't see any double negatives.  To answer your question, A is correct.  Using "hadn't" (the past perfect tense) shows that the renting happened sometime in the past, before the party.  I think B does not give any idea of when the car was rented, or even if it has been rented yet.